# php mysql check if username exists

Tags: php, mysql

i know maybe this post will be marked soon as duplicate, because there are a lot of questions answered but i dont know why it is not working for me (as always) here is this part of code:

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username='".$username."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

echo "exists";
}else{
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
    echo "free";
}
}
}
```

**Problem is** : I'm always getting "Free"

thanks

-Nick

Comment: You should turn on error reporting. `mysql_*` function are removed in PHP 7! You are open for a nice SQL injection.

Comment: Your code is at risk of SQL Injections attacks, also stop using mysql_8 extensions you should use mysqli_* or PDO extension.

Comment: Please consider using PDO or mysqli, very vulnerable here for injection!

Comment: ok then, any good tuts? or other thing so i can get more info about it?

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated, you should be using `mysqli`. Have have you tried running the code in your `SQL` and see the result replacing your variables with existing values in your table?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the query you're creating works when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: yes it works, guys told me i should use mysqli, because mysql is deprecated (whats difference why they did this?)

Comment: mysqli_, the i stands for "improved".

Comment: i just edited post

Comment: Two words for all this: *"Just wow"*.

Comment: @Nick are you sure you are getting `$username` correctly? Just check in case by `echo` or just by a test name. Print your query by `echo` and try that again in directly in database. You will probably have your answer.

Comment: strange situation: SOMEBODY DOWNVOTED QUESTION THAT HAS NO CORRECT ANSWERS wtf god :Dd

Comment: @JayPatel yes i am getting username and pass correct, i found that numrows is always zero, idk why

Comment: I am asking silly question here, but have you tried `"SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username='test' "`(assuming `test` is a user already in the database - not using a PHP variable here for the user name) in this same code? and after trying this are you getting 0 number of rows returned? @Nick

Comment: @JayPatel yes, i tried this too and it's working, i cant imagine why this happens

Comment: You have accepted some answer. So I hope your problem is resolved. If yes, what was the problem? I am sure it was something little and tricky. @Nick

Comment: @JayPatel yes answer was not answering directly my question, but it helped me tho. the problem was that $username and $password variables in Config.php file and index file were same, thus, it was connecting to database using variables that user was submitting.

Comment: @Nick ohh..Okay..Thanks..As I said, it was something little and tricky..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching the values and then using the php count() function on the query result. If count is greater than 0 echo taken else free

Comment: yes that is the problem,  numrows is always 0 and i dont know why, because there are some records in DB

Comment: Check if you connection is happening

Comment: it is, i checked + in other parts of code everything with connection is ok. BTW to make you people more confused: `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($usernameG&&$passwordG){
 if($numrows!=0){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $dbusername = $row['username'];
   $dbpassword = $row['password'];
  }
  if($usernameG==$dbusername && $passwordG==$dbpassword){
   $_SESSION['username']=$usernameG;
   header('Location: menu.php');
  }else{
  echo "wrong";
 }
 }else{
  echo "wrong"
 }
}` that's working.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use a password in this query if you only want to check is a username is available? Did you also dumped the $numrows var to see which data it contains?

I would use something like

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='username' LIMIT 1
```

You want to know if a username is available, so stop looking after you found 1 (LIMIT 1). If I ask you to find me 1 spoon,
As many others suggest, stop using the deprecated mysql_* functions. Try reading the tutorials on https://phpdelusions.net/pdo (much more can be found via Google)

When using PDO I think you can use the following code. Forgive me if it contains errors, it has been ages since I just PDO directly:

```
<?php

$checkUser = $pdoConnection->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
$checkUser->execute([$username]);

if ( $checkUser->rowCount() == 1 )
{
    return 'Username exists';
}

# Username is available, so continue with the rest of your code
```

Small tip from me, based on experience, which has nothing to do with your question; never use capitals in your database. It could lead to unnecessary problems.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't make sense, i already tried with LIMIT 1, find only username, (logically u find pass and username or only username give yo username results) but it doesnt work!

Comment: Well, first let me thank you for marking my answer (attempt in helping you) as not useful (useless). What happens when you dump your $numrows var? Does it contains the data your expecting?

Comment: ok first i didnt downvote it, as you can see i have only 43 reputation not 125,  and yes $numrows has no data, it always shows me "0"

Answer (score -2):

Your Username and Password are in quotes, so it is taking them literally.

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username='" . $usernameG . "' and Password='" . $passwordG ."'");//quotes
```

Comment: That's wrong. The whole string is wrapped in double quotes, which means that single quotes inside it don't get any special treatment, and variables are interpolated. It's the quotes on the outside of the string that are important.